# Ajax is not connecting to php server because of pending Network situation

Tags: javascript, php, pending-transition

I have an unknown situation that AJAX request does not reach to the PHP server.
There is no error code in the Chrome browser, but it's not reaching the PHP GET method.

In my code

```js
function GetLectureData(SID){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
        data: {"SID_key": SID},
        Type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('DB정보 접근성공- ', data);
            if(data != null)    {
                for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
                {
                    var flags=true;
                    lectrueInfo=data[i].classroom.split('-');
                    Lecture[i] = lectrueInfo[1];
                    Lecture[i] = Lecture[i].slice(1,4)+"호";
                    console.log(Lecture[i]+"  "+count);
                    count++;
                    if(typeof Lecture[i]== "undefined")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    for(var j=0;j<i; j++)
                    {
                        if(Lecture[i]==Lecture[j])
                        {
                            flags = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if(flags == true)
                    {
                       Create(Lecture[i]);
                    }

                }
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            console.log('실패 - ', xhr);
        }
    });
}
```

```php
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/javascript;charset=UTF-8');

$user = 'hyumini';
$pw = 'hyu(e)mini';
$db = 'hyumini';
$host ='localhost';
$port = 3306;
$table = 'LectureSchedule';

$my_db = new mysqli($host,$user,$pw,$db,$port);

mysqli_query($my_db,"set names utf8");
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        echo mysqli_connect_errno();
        exit;
}
$q=$_GET["SID_key"];

$callback = $_REQUEST['callback'];
$return_array = array();
$count = 0;

$rs = mysqli_query($my_db, "select DISTINCT  LectureSchedule.classroom
from ConnectLecture JOIN LectureSchedule 
ON ConnectLecture.SID = $q AND ConnectLecture.lectureID = LectureSchedule.lectureID");


while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
{
 $array[] = $data;
}


$my_db->close();

$json_val = json_encode($array);


echo $callback."(".$json_val.")";
?>
```

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnNBa.png) is my result
[pending situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnIlR.png)

I'm really wondering why this is occurring in this situation.

Comment: You are passing data as if you're attempting to POST, try passing as a URL query string i.e `data: "SID_key=value"`, also, declare type before data.

Comment: You're specifying `callback` as your jsonpCallback, but I don't see a function named `callback` defined in the code you posted.

Comment: @Kisaragi if you're specifying `GET` as your type then data will be appended to the query string. And the order in which you declare the properties of the ajax options does not matter.

Comment: see the example code in your anwer becaus im beginner coder

Comment: i want to get new solution in this comment not understand about answer

Answer (score 2):

Click on that request in your result you show in network panel, the **connection established** and if request pending cause of Time To First Byte (**TTFB**)-> it means problem in php code,

Else if connection **not** established firstly then this request is in **stole** mode. which means few more request is in pending before this request. so this request will response after previous request complete.

Comment: In other words, are you getting a 200 response code? What is the http status code you're getting in the response?

Comment: No response, because not accept respond to PHP server,

Comment: No response code. so it is occurring to pending situation. not accept the respond

Comment: did you check is it in ttfb mode.?